# Could NOT find LMDB (missing: LMDB_INCLUDE_DIR LMDB_LIBRARIES)

Tags: c++, cmake, lmdb, glog, gflags

Windows 10
Visual Studio 14

I am trying to build a c++ code based on [this github repository](https://github.com/D-X-Y/caffe-faster-rcnn/tree/dev).
However, when I try to generate lib files in **Cmake** I get this error:

[image]

How can I make it recognize LMDB, GFALGS, and GLOG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I'm not allowed to comment yet, but I would like to point you to the documentation: [FindHDF5](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindHDF5.html).

I can't find anything about **HDF5_DIR** but I did find **HDF5_ROOT**.

> HDF5_ROOT
>
> Specify the path to the HDF5 installation to use.

Comment: Thanks. I configured again and the error changed to LMDB.

Comment: Just follow the same pattern, look for Find*.cmake module in that gitrep and specify the needed flags. For the above example it's already specifying that you want to set **GFLAGS_ROOT_DIR** and **GLOG_ROOT_DIR** to the root directories of those packages.